# nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "equ_config" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis, yugabytedb

I'm developing a backend program with springboot + mybatis + Yugabyte.
It works well in the development environment, but got following errors in online environment :

```
2021-04-14 13:52:15.123 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG com.yoi.config.infrastructure.repository.mapper.ConfigMapper.liteConfigByType - ==&gt;  Preparing: select * from "equ_config" where conf_type = ? and conf_df = true order by conf_order desc; 
2021-04-14 13:52:15.133 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG com.yoi.config.infrastructure.repository.mapper.ConfigMapper.liteConfigByType - ==&gt; Parameters: dept(String)
2021-04-14 13:52:15.459 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "equ_config" does not exist
  Position: 16
### The error may exist in URL [jar:file:/srvmgmt/java/target/equip-management-server.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/mapper/ConfigMapper.xml]
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from  "equ_config" where conf_type = ? and conf_df = true         order by conf_order desc;
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "equ_config" does not exist
  Position: 16
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "equ_config" does not exist
  Position: 16] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "equ_config" does not exist
  Position: 16
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
```

The Mapper is like following :

```
    <select id="liteConfigByType" resultType="com.yoi.config.infrastructure.repository.po.ConfigPO">
     select * from  equ_config where conf_type = #{type} and conf_df = true
        order by conf_order desc;
    </select>
```

The query sql `select * from  equ_config where conf_type = 'dept' and conf_df = true order by conf_order desc;` works well in the Navicat Gui, and the online application starts up well.

I don't know what goes wrong.

Comment: 1) Does Navicat Gui still work if you run the same query, i.e. quoting the table name: `"equ_config"`? --- 2) Are you sure that the application and Navicat Gui are connected to the same database? --- 3) Are they logged in with the same user? If not, is the user the application uses authorized to see the table?

Comment: @Andreas In the Navicat Gui both table name "equ_config" and equ_config work well.

The application in development environment ,online environment and the Navicat GUI all connect to the same database.

The use is the same one .But I found the password is different. I am not sure whether it has affect .

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake here .How could one account have two different password ?
I need check again whether the Navicat GUI and the online application connect to the same DataSource .
Thanks for your heuristic question.
@Andreas

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a configuration issue somewhere. Without more information, it's difficult to find out the root cause of the issue. It could be that:

- The table was not actually created.
- The grants were not set up correctly.
- The account may be different in PROD.
- May have a different case in the table name, or a prefix, or a suffix.
- you name it...

A trick that can help you diagnose the issue can take que form of a query on the `information_schema`, ran from the application itself, to find out what the application is seeing. I have a few "extra" queries in my MyBatis mappers that look like:

```
<select id="searchTable" resultType="FoundTableVO">
  select table_schema, table_name
  from information_schema.tables
  where lower(table_name) like '%equ_config%'
</select>
```

The above query will list all the tables that look like your table, and the schema where they are located. A few queries like this one will shed light on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the table equ_config is in the schema public. If it's not, try this syntax using qweries with your table: "schema_name.equ_config"

Comment: Yes, the equ_config table is in the public scheme.
Although the default schema is public,  , I still  add `currentSchema=public` in the DataSource url.